# How to access Google Assistant commands (IFTTT vs DialogFlow)?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, ifttt, google-assist-api

If I have a command for my google assistant to open windows in my house. To complete this request i have a web-hook which is implemented. eg. `mywebsite.com/api/open-window`

--

#### Approach 1

When i use the command `Open all windows`

The google assistant connects to IFTTT which has an applet setup for this.

That applet now connects to my web-hook

--

#### Approach 2

If i have a DialogFlow assistant called `Dr. Autobot`

When i use the command `Ask Dr. Autobot to Open all windows`

The google assistant connects to my DialogFlow which has intents and actions setup

That fulfilment now connects to my web-hook.

--

How do I implement the Approach 1 without using IFTTT?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [smart home platform](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) to make direct calls to your Action based on device types that your Action provides to the user.